# miniforge can't initiate jupyter notebook

Tags: apple-silicon

I have installed `Miniforge` on my macbook air m1, and then did the following steps to successfully install jupyter and launch it:

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
source ~/miniforge3/bin/activate
```

```
mkdir data-science
cd data-science
```

```
conda create --prefix ./env python=3.8
conda activate ./env
```

```
conda install -y jupyter 
conda install pandas numpy matplotlib scikit-learn tqdm
```

Then: I launched Jupyter this way:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Everything worked fine. But when I exited the terminal and opened again and typed:

```
jupyter notebook
```

I got this error: `zsh: command not found: jupyter`

What is the problem?

I know that this is a path problem, but even when I go to `env` environment, and I run `jupyter notebook` I get the same command error.

Comment: Did you rerun `conda activate ./env` in the new terminal?

Comment: Yes. It gave this error: environmentlocationnotfound, it's bizzare. Do you know how to completely remove miniforge that I installed to install it again?

Comment: What is the content of `~/data-science/env`?

Comment: Everything that is done with the above command lines, I didn't add anything.

Comment: Please run `cat ~/data-science/env` and add the result to the question. Rerun `cd ~/data-science; conda activate ./env` and also add the result to the question using copy/paste from Terminal.